# How to test for the endogeneity between variables? which tests i should use?

Tags: econometrics, stata, economics

my thesis is about measuring the impact of population growth on the economic growth in my country. However, i should test for the endogeneity between the variables chosen. for the dependent variable i chose the GDP growth rate and for the independent variables i chose the population density, fertility rates, life expectancy at birth, exports growth rate, crude death rates and government expenditures. How to test for endogeneity between these variables? which tests should i use? i know that if it appears to be a problem i should use IV but how to know if my model suffers from such a problem? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Endogeneity is evaluated first of all from a theoretical point of view, having a hard look at your research design, the relationship of interest, and the variables you are considering. Endogeneity in itself may arise from different causes (simultaneity/reverse causality, omitted variables, measurement error), some of which cannot be throughly empirically tested. For example, there is no definitive empirical test for omitted variables; this is rather a theoretical point of whether all key variables and confounders are accounted for. Most Instrumental Variables strategies are justified ex-ante, while the empirical testing focuses on whether the chosen IV works as intended.

The reference literature is always a good starting point. Most likely other scholars have already faced the same issues. Endogeneity is a pervasive concern in empirical studies. This assessment may then inform your decision of pursuing a specific identification strategy, model, or testing.

Overall, your goal shuold be to build a convincing case that your model is the best feasible option (which may imply sharing some of the limitations of existing research).